# stop / start windows service using findstr

Tags: service, findstr

I need to stop and start a service when certain parameters are met in a .txt file.

When my app can't connect to a database in our test environment (regular occurence) it generates the following file type in the server folder (file date changes with each occurence)

**SelfTest-20141126181000-RED.txt**

Within this file is the phrase

**RED: Server failed to start: Unable to open database: Unable to connect to database**

Every time this is generated, along with this phrase I need to stop and start a specific service.

I have never used findstr command but I think it could be useful here. Textfile needs wildcarding obviously, and i would like a results file generating with the data and time service was stopped and started. 
Would the following work?

```
findstr "RED: Server failed to start: Unable to open database: Unable to connect to database” *RED.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
sc stop "my service"
sc start "my service"
echo %DATE% %TIME% database >> results.txt
)
```

Plan is to then have this running through scheduled tasks every 30mins or so

Comment: Wouldn't it be a **lot** easier to do this from within your app?

Comment: Sorry, maybe app was the wrong word. This is a program installed on the windows server itself, which runs as a service. it is this program that talks out to an Oracle database, when this database isn't available springs the RED .txt doc.

Comment: So, the service that writes the file is also the service that needs to be restarted? Presumably you have no source code for that service? Because if you do, why not have the service restart itself? `sc stop` just sends a message via the Service Control Manager.

Comment: Absolutely right on both counts. It is the same service that needs restarting, and we have no source code. So I was looking for the best way to stop the service (which generates a flag to our work queue when stopped - so i know about it) when the database is unreachable. Otherwise it keeps going ad nauseum trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously once you have one such file, your script will continue to find it and restart your service every 30 minutes. You'd need to delete or move the RED file.

The second problem is that the `sc start` command may fail while the service is still being stopped - `sc stop` returns as soon as the request is delivered, and does not wait. You'd need a repeated `sc query "ServiceName" | find "RUNNING"` check. And while the service is still running, give it some more time by running `ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul`. Busy-waiting isn't nice, but there's no clean `sleep` command so `ping` is the common hack for that.

Comment: Thanks for this. To be honest, I'd be happy just for the service to just stop and then not attempt a start. At least that way I will be flagged re the issue and take action. Then I can manually start it when i'm ready. So taking out the sc start option does the rest of teh code look sound? I was unsure re the wildcarding format of the RED file.

Comment: findstr helptext stated that period was a wildcard and asterisk formed a repeat function - so wasn't 100% if it was .RED.txt or *RED.txt

Comment: No, that's the search string regex syntax.